# Must provide path to nupic core release. export NUPIC_CORE_RELEASE=<path>

Tags: ubuntu, nupic

While installing nupic package for Ubuntu - 14.04 LTS using instructions from [Nupic Install](https://github.com/numenta/nupic/wiki/Installing-NuPIC-on-Ubuntu). I keep getting exception as stated below

> Exception: Must provide path to nupic core release. export
>   NUPIC_CORE_RELEASE=

As an alternative when I try building from source I get: "capnp missing include path"

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Things are a little shaky in NuPIC world right now. We are having some build issues and working to simplify things. Can you pull the latest code and try again? I think we have fixed [the issue that was originally blocking you](https://github.com/numenta/nupic.core/pull/552).

You will still need to [install Cap'n Proto 0.5.2 yourself](https://capnproto.org/install.html), however. How you do this is up to you.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. But none of the options worked. It stays same. Will wait for now.

Comment: The same happens on MacOS 10.10.5, python 2.7.10, nupic-0.3.0, nupic.bindings-0.1.5. Look here for full coverage of this issue: https://github.com/numenta/nupic/issues/2543

Comment: Hey all, please try again. We have made some changes that should fix things, but you'll need to ensure you've uninstalled everything first, so run `pip uninstall nupic -y; pip uninstall nupic.bindings -y` a few times.